# Refreshing an Access Token p2/OAuth2 iOS

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, alamofire

I'm using p2/OAuth2 with Alamofire v4 as explained in documentation [here](https://github.com/p2/OAuth2/wiki/Alamofire-4)

```
let sessionManager = SessionManager()
let retrier = OAuth2RetryHandler(oauth2: <# your OAuth2 instance #>)
sessionManager.adapter = retrier
sessionManager.retrier = retrier
self.alamofireManager = sessionManager   // you must hold on to this somewhere
// Note that the `validate()` call here is important
sessionManager.request("https://api.github.com/user").validate().responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

```
import Foundation
import OAuth2
import Alamofire


class OAuth2RetryHandler: RequestRetrier, RequestAdapter {

    let loader: OAuth2DataLoader

    init(oauth2: OAuth2) {
        loader = OAuth2DataLoader(oauth2: oauth2)
    }

    /// Intercept 401 and do an OAuth2 authorization.
    public func should(_ manager: SessionManager, retry request: Request, with error: Error, completion: @escaping RequestRetryCompletion) {
        if let response = request.task?.response as? HTTPURLResponse, 401 == response.statusCode, let req = request.request {
            var dataRequest = OAuth2DataRequest(request: req, callback: { _ in })
            dataRequest.context = completion
            loader.enqueue(request: dataRequest)
            loader.attemptToAuthorize() { authParams, error in
                guard error?.asOAuth2Error != .alreadyAuthorizing else {
                    // Don't dequeue requests if we are waiting for other authorization request
                    return
                }
                self.loader.dequeueAndApply() { req in
                    if let comp = req.context as? RequestRetryCompletion {
                        comp(nil != authParams, 0.0)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            completion(false, 0.0)   // not a 401, not our problem
        }
    }

    /// Sign the request with the access token.
    public func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest) throws -> URLRequest {
        guard nil != loader.oauth2.accessToken else {
            return urlRequest
        }
        return try urlRequest.signed(with: loader.oauth2)   // "try" added in 3.0.2
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine, but what I want to achieve is to avoid 401 errors by fetching an access token if expired before submitting a request.

Is it possible to achieve this approach ?

Thanks in advance,
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Well the standard behaviour in a mobile app should be as follows:

- Login and get access token + refresh token
- Optionally store tokens in secure storage so that logins on every app restart are avoided
- Use access token to call the API and handle 401 responses via a token renewal
- Use the refresh token to renew the access token when needed
- Eventually the refresh token expires and the user has to login again

You can never completely avoid 401 responses from the API, and UIs need to handle this response specially. It is possible as an optimisation to refresh tokens silently in the background, before the 'exp' claim from the current access token is reached.

Out of interest there is an [iOS Code Sample](https://authguidance.com/2020/02/22/how-to-run-the-ios-code-sample/) of mine that is easy to run, and which allows a kind of testing of the expiry events. This may give you some ideas on how to adapt your own solution.

Comment: Thank you Gary for you answer, I'm interested about your suggestion to refresh token silently in the background before it expire, is there any chance to do that with my current library p2/OAuth2 ?